# Existence of left and right sided limits implies a function $f : [a,b]\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is regulated

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to find the hole in the proof. What I think it is:

There's a hole in the part where we prove that "$f$ is regulated implies that left and right limits exist". Namely, we forget to prove for the right-sided limit $f(x+)$.

Here is my amendment:

Let $x ∈ (a, b]$ and $x_n →
x+$. Let $ϕ_k ∈ S[a, b] $such that $||f − ϕ||_{∞} <
1/k$

For any $k$, there exists $δ_k$ such that
$ϕ_k$ is constant on $(x, x+\delta_k)$. Then there exists $N_k$ such that $|x_n −x| < δ_k$ if $n > N_k$,
and
$$|f(x_m)-f(x_n)| \lt \frac{2}{k}$$

$\forall m,n \gt N_k$. So $(f(x_n))_{n \geq 1}$ is cauchy, hence convergent. Let $f(x+)$ denote its limit.

If $(x^{'}_n)$ is another sequence that converges to $x+$, we can consider the mixed sequence $(x^{"}_n=(x_1,x^{'}_1,x_2,x^{'}_2,...)$. We have $x^{"}_n \rightarrow x+$, so $f(x^{"}_n)$ is Cauchy by the above argument, hence convergent. All its subsequences converge to the same imit, so $f(x^{'}_n)\rightarrow f(x+)$ as well.

Would this be correct?

Comment: It is true that this was missing from the proof, though it would usually be included with a line like "the proof for $f(x+)$ is identical". However, note that in the 2nd part, all the proof uses is that $f(x+)$ exists for $x \in [a,b)$ and $f(b-)$ exists. It does not make use of the existence of $f(x-)$ for any $x \in (a,b)$. But by the first part, such existence would then hold. I.e., it would appear to be a proof that if the upper limits exist everywhere, and the lower limit at $b$, then the lower limits exist everywhere as well. But this is false. So the hole must be in the 2nd part.

Comment: One example where the upper limit exists everywhere but lower limit does not exist everywhere would be $$f(x) =\begin{cases} \sin(1/x)& x \in [-1,0)\\0&x\in [0,1]\end{cases}$$